# How to provide validation with single button in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two buttons on single form.
First button used to upload file and second button is submit .
**I want validation , when i clicked on submit button that time validation should be generate**.
But in my application when i clicked on upload button that time validation generated.

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Document", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

<table>

 <tr>
                <td >
                  File Name:
                </td>
                <td >
                    <%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.document.DOCUMENT_NAME) %>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.document.DOCUMENT_NAME) %>
                </td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>               
                    Select File:
                </td>
                <td>          
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="height: 24px" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Upload" />
                </td>
<tr>
</table>

 <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Create" />
</div

<%}%>
```

Controller:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "DOCUMENT NAME")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string DOCUMENT_NAME
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your code? especially the view.

Comment: Generally form submit button shows the validation errors. Both the buttons are submit buttons?

Comment: Yes both buttons are subimit buttons.

Comment: Could you share your view code?

Comment: What I find is the any submit button pressed first will show you the validation message. I have one question, Is there any special requirement for submit button for fileupload? because the last submit button will also post the file that can be accessed with "HttpPostedFileBase object", in your controller. This can solve your issue.

Comment: When i clicked on first submit button that time i provide file name in Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Any button on form (and You have two) will trigger validation. One of possibile solutions is replace upload button by some  element and do uploading via jquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check which button is click like below

View:

```
<div>          
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="height: 24px" />
<input type="submit" id="btnUpload" name="submitButton" value="Upload" />
</div>

 <div>
<input type="submit" id="btnCreate" name="submitButton" value="Create" />
</div
```

controller

```
public ActionResult actionName(string btnUpload,string btnCreate)
{
  //now you can easily check here for which button is clicked

if(btnUpload != null || btnUpload !="")
{
 //perform uploading logic here
}
if(btnCreate!=null || btnCreate !="")
{
 //perform your validation here
} 
}
```

i hope this will help you.